# Regular Expressions required format

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate following text using regular expressions

integer(1..any)/'fs' or 'sf'/ + or - /integer(1..any)/(h) or (m) or (d)

samples :

```
1) 8fs+60h
2) 10sf-30m
3) 2fs+3h
3) 15sf-20m
```

i tried with this

```
function checkRegx(str,id){
    var arr = strSplit(str);
    var regx_FS =/\wFS\w|\d{0,9}\d[hmd]/gi;

    for (var i in arr){
            var str_ = arr[i];
            console.log(str_);
            var is_ok = str_.match(regx_FS);
            var err_pos = str_.search(regx_FS);                
            if(is_ok){
              console.log(' ID from ok ' + id);
              $('#'+id).text('Format Error');
              break;
            }else{
              console.log(' ID from fail ' + id);
              $('#'+id).text('');
            } 
     }  
 }
```

but it is not working

please can any one help me to make this correct

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you want the regular expression to match. Perhaps a plain word explanation along with some examples of matching input might help.

Comment: I always use this site for matching up regex for a start

http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^[1-9]\d*(?:fs|sf)[-+][1-9]\d*[hmd]$/i
```

You were close, but you seem to be missing some basic regex comprehension.

First of all, the `^` and `$` just make sure you're matching the entire string. Otherwise any junk before or after will count as valid.

The formation `[1-9]\d*` allows for any integer from 1 upwards (and any number of digits long).

`(?:fs|sf)` is an alternation (the `?:` is to make the group non-capturing) to allow for both options.

`[-+]` and `[hmd]` are character classes allowing to match any one of the characters in there.

That final `i` allows the letters to be lowercase or uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the expression you tried relates anyhow to the description you gave us. What you want is

```
/\d+(fs|sf)[+-]\d+[hmd]/
```

Since you seem to know a bit about [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) I won't give a step-by-step explanation :-)

If you need exclude zero from the "integer" matches, use `[1-9]\d*` instead. Not sure whether by "*(1..any)*" you meant the number of digits or the number itself.

Looking on the code, you

- [should not use `for in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)
- will need [string start and end anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to check whether `_str` exactly matches the regex (instead of only some part)
- don't need the *global* flag on the regex
- rather might use the [RegExp `test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) than `match` - you don't need a result string but only whether it did match or not
- are not using the `err_pos` variable anywhere, and it hardly will work with `search`

```
function checkRegx(str, id) {
    var arr = strSplit(str);
    var regx_FS = /^\d+(fs|sf)[+-]\d+[hmd]$/i;

    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var str = arr[i];
        console.log(str);
        if (regx_FS.test(str) {
            console.log(' ID from ok ' + id);
            $('#'+id).text('Format Error');
            break;
        } else {
            console.log(' ID from fail ' + id);
            $('#'+id).text('');
        } 
    }  
}
```

Btw, it would be better to separate the validation (regex, array split, iteration) from the output (id, jQuery, logs) into two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
/^\d+(?:fs|sf)[-+]\d+[hmd]$/i
```

Comment: Please notice the difference between character classes and (capturing) groups! Btw, your "integer" does not match the `60` from the example

Comment: looks quite similar to Bergi's answer now

Comment: True, haven't seen it sorry. Should I delete my post ?

Comment: @Scalpweb There's not necessarily a reason to delete your answer if you independently came to the same answer as another answer. There are some potentially meaningful differences between the answers anyway.